# Align two contents with flex-container

Tags: html, css

I would like to align some contents as per the image below.
This is my jsfiddle code. https://jsfiddle.net/27ay5s4t/1/
In reality I can't fix the contents in the same position.
Could someone help me out.
Thank you.

Code

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid #333;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container>div {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="preview"><span style="color:cyan;font-size:30px;">21 °</span></div>
  <div id="preview1">
    <marquee><span style="color:red;font-size:30px;">Rina rilancia sullo smart working che sale da otto a dodici giorni al mese, L’azienda ha firmato un  accordo con i sindacati nazionali dei trasporti che riguarda 1.600 dipendenti in Italia - In Tim spunta la proposta di 1.300 uscite volontarie e incentivate per il 2021, La società ha incontrato i sindacati ai quali ha sottoposto l’ipotesi di una riduzione del personale in base all’art.4 della Legge Fornero, sulla falsariga dell’accordo fatto nel precedente piano industriale  - Lungo la Brebemi debuttano le ricariche elettriche per le auto Tesla, La direttissima Brescia-Milano si conferma l’autostrada più green d’Italia - Spirits, Branca international rilancia sulla sostenibilità, Investimento nel Progetto Selvatiq, sostegno al Wild Nomadic Spirits - Lhm gestirà Palazzo Velabro a Roma con Design hotels By Marriott, Interior design curato dallo Studio Garibaldi Architects - </span></marquee>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="preview"><span style="color:white;font-size:30px;">H24</span>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/67" width="67" height="67" style="padding:20px;"></div>
  <div id="preview1">
    <marquee><span style="color:red;font-size:30px;">Rina rilancia sullo smart working che sale da otto a dodici giorni al mese, L’azienda ha firmato un  accordo con i sindacati nazionali dei trasporti che riguarda 1.600 dipendenti in Italia - In Tim spunta la proposta di 1.300 uscite volontarie e incentivate per il 2021, La società ha incontrato i sindacati ai quali ha sottoposto l’ipotesi di una riduzione del personale in base all’art.4 della Legge Fornero, sulla falsariga dell’accordo fatto nel precedente piano industriale  - Lungo la Brebemi debuttano le ricariche elettriche per le auto Tesla, La direttissima Brescia-Milano si conferma l’autostrada più green d’Italia - Spirits, Branca international rilancia sulla sostenibilità, Investimento nel Progetto Selvatiq, sostegno al Wild Nomadic Spirits - Lhm gestirà Palazzo Velabro a Roma con Design hotels By Marriott, Interior design curato dallo Studio Garibaldi Architects - </span></marquee>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try add `display: inherit;`,  `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` for `.flex-container > div {}` in css.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nz398fek/

HTML:

```
...
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="preview">
      <span style="color:white;">H24</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/67">
    </div>

    <div id="preview1">
      <marquee>
        <span style="color:red;">Text Here</span>
      </marquee>
    </div>
  </div>
...
```

CSS:

```
...
.flex-container {
  ...
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around; /* OR space-between */
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#preview {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
...
```

To learn more about Flexbox visit: https://flexbox.help/

Comment: Thank you. With your solution, the information is aligned. What can I do to lower only the red text of the <marquee> tag?

Comment: add space-between in .flex-container